symbol _ZTINSt13__future_base12_Result_baseE version GLIBCXX_3.4.23 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
I am using x-tools to compile a .so for PiOS legacy 32bit. I run in to a problem when i try to execute a program on the Pi that has libpaho-mqttpp3.so as a dependency; whereby I get the above error.
When I run
objdump -T /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX

I see that the symbol it is complaining about is included in GLIBCXX_3.4.15 but not in 3.4.23.
Ive tried changing glibc versions in my cross compiler however I'm not familiar enough with this type of error to really know where I'm going wrong.
Anyone know where to start?
Ive tried changing glibc versions in my cross compiler and reinstalled/changed versions of libstdc on the Pi, however I'm not familiar enough with this type of error to really know where I'm going wrong. Anyone know where to start?

Your problem has nothing to do with GLIBC.
Read this answer.
GLIBCXX_3.4.23 corresponds to GCC 7.1.0. This means that libpaho-mqttpp3.so was compiled/linked using GCC-7.1.0 or above, but on the target your libstdc++.so.6 is from an earlier GCC release.
You must either upgrade your libstdc++.so.6 on the target, or re-build libpaho-mqttpp3.so with an earlier revision of GCC (one that matches your target libstdc++.so.6).
